# Need a wiki with a nice GUI

Tags: gui, wiki

My grandfather in law wants to put together a wiki, but wikimedia's syntax is to complicated for him. Is there a nice wiki software I can install on my ubuntu server with a GUI to edit tables, links and everything else?

Answer (score 1):

[Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) is fantastic, but it will set you back $10 for 10 users unless your grandfather in law is a non-profit or open source project.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [gitit](http://gitit.net/).

It has a web frontend and uses [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) for markup. Pandoc supports a number of input formats, most notably an extended version of markdown.

Answer (score 0):

### [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/)

It's super easy to install, doesn't even need a database and is easier to configure and use than the classic MediaWiki. The input format is very simple, of course it has a text editor with buttons for markup, too.

Also, there are tons of plugins and themes that make it even more useful. So you might want to use another text editor instead of the built-in.

I really love it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Drupal](http://cwgordon.com/how-to-create-a-wiki-with-drupal). Simply install a WYSIWYG editor as a default editing engine, and set up the whole Drupal installation. Yes, you will have to maintain the site sometimes (like updating the core and modules), but that's it.

EDIT: Here is a [whole](http://drupal.org/project/drupal_wiki) 'install group'.

Answer (score 0):

Mediawiki (**<1.18**) with [WYSIWYG](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WYSIWYG) CK-editor?